# Java Web Start blocked with newest Java version

Tags: java, glassfish

I have an Application Client deployed on a local Glassfish 4.1 with Java 8u20 installed. Now whenever I try to start the client on the localhost (same machine) using Java Web Start it gets blocked by Java Security with the message:

> **Location:** `http://localhost:8080`
>   **Reason:** The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in  the Java Control Panel.

I added localhost to the Exception Site List with following entries:

```
file:///
http://localhost
http://127.0.0.1
http://localhost.localdomain
```

then I even imported the Glassfish self-signed certificate as a Trusted Certificate in the Java Control Panel. Finally I enabled Mixed code and disabled certificate revocation checks in the Control panel. But still my application gets blocked.

As the medium Security level is not available anymore, what can I do further?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a javaws from a java 1.7 u25 or earlier, your application client will work.

I have the same problem with Java8u31.  My application client won't start with a javaws later than u25, but if is use u25 or under it will.

So, I use u25 to start the application client, but the application runs in the java 1.8 u31 environment.

I also cannot get the exception site list to work.  I starting to think their is a bug in java here.

I tried to replace the s1as certificate in glassfish per these instructions to no avail.  https://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/glassfish_java_web_start_and

Not sure that it is possible to have glassfish automatically sign an application client with the new security restrictions!